# How may I change a JSON object in a specific location depending on another attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```
{
  "employees": [
    { "firstName":"John" , "lastName":"Doe" }, 
    { "firstName":"Anna" , "lastName":"Smith" }, 
    { "firstName":"Peter" , "lastName":"Jones" }
  ]
}
```

How can we alter John's Last Name ? (without knowing it's Doe)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `$.each` utility function:

```
$.each(obj.employees, function(i, v){
   if (v.firstName === 'John') {  
       v.lastName = 'newValue'
       // return false
   }
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g7tzK/

---

You can also use the native `for` loop.

```
for (var i = 0; i < obj.employees.length; i++) {
   if (obj.employees[i].firstName === 'John') {
      obj.employees[i].lastName = 'newValue';
      return false;
   }
}
```

Comment: You could also use a for-loop, which is even cleaner…

Comment: I think this is cleaner, with the for you need to get the number of elements

Comment: This will not alter obj.employees, it will modify the var 'v' inside the each scope... I believe you have to do obj.employees[i] = 'newValue' to modify the original object. EDIT: I was wrong. see down.

Comment: @Aktee This alters the actual object's property.

Comment: What is the purpose of returning false, I know this is very obvious for everyone.. I'm sorry, but I haven't gotten it yet

Comment: @PedroEsperança It stops the loop from being executed.

Answer (score 1):

no need for jQuery:

```
for(var i in obj.employees)
{
    if(obj.employees[i].firstName == 'John')
    {
            obj.employees[i].lastName = "newValue";
    }
}
```